# Re partitioning using pyspark failing with error

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have parquet in s3 folder with below column.Size of the parquet is around 40 mb.

```
org_id, device_id, channel_id, source, col1, col2
```

right now partition is on 3 column `org_id device_id channel_id`

I want change the partition to `source,  org_id, device_id, channel_id.` 
I am using pyspark to read file from s3 and write to s3 bucket.

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="parquet_ingestion1").getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
file_path = "s3://some-bucket/some_folder"
print("Reading parquet from s3:{}".format(file_path))
spark_df = spark.read.parquet(file_path)
print("Converting to parquet")
file_path_re = "s3://other_bucket/re-partition"
partition_columns = ["source", "org_id", "device_id", "channel_id "]

spark_df.repartition(1).write.partitionBy(partition_columns).mode('append').parquet(file_path_re)
```

I am getting error and parquet file is not generated.

```
spark_df.repartition(1).write.partitionBy(partition_columns).mode('append').parquet(file_path_re)
[Stage 1:>                                                        (0 + 8) / 224]20/04/29 13:29:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, ip-172-31-43-0.ap-south-1.compute.internal, executor 3): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainFloatDictionary
        at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToBinary(Dictionary.java:41)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToBinary(ParquetDictionary.java:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.WritableColumnVector.getUTF8String(WritableColumnVector.java:380)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:148)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Then i tried

```
spark_df.write.partitionBy(partition_columns).mode('append').parquet(file_path_re)


spark_df.write.partitionBy(partition_columns).mode('append').parquet(file_path_re)
[Stage 3:>                                                        (0 + 8) / 224]20/04/29 13:32:11 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 23, ip-172-31-42-4.ap-south-1.compute.internal, executor 5): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainFloatDictionary
        at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToBinary(Dictionary.java:41)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToBinary(ParquetDictionary.java:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.WritableColumnVector.getUTF8String(WritableColumnVector.java:380)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:216)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec$$anonfun$1.apply(SortExec.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec$$anonfun$1.apply(SortExec.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[Stage 3:==>                                                      (8 + 8) / 224]20/04/29 13:32:22 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 3.0 (TID 40, ip-172-31-42-4.ap-south-1.compute.internal, executor 5): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainFloatDictionary
        at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToBinary(Dictionary.java:41)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToBinary(ParquetDictionary.java:51)
```

In 2nd case it is giving failure but it is creating parquet also.Now i am not sure it is correctly creating all the data to new partition .
Let me know how is correct way of re partitioning the parquet.

UPDATE 1:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
for col1 in partition_columns:
    spark_df=spark_df.withColumn(col1, col(col1).cast(dataType=StringType()))
```

Tried both 
spark_df.repartition(1).write.partitionBy(partition_columns).mode('append').parquet(file_path_re)

spark_df.write.partitionBy(partition_columns).mode('append').parquet(file_path_re)
I get following error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 20, ip-172-31-42-4.ap-south-1.compute.internal, executor 4): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainFloatDictionary
        at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToBinary(Dictionary.java:41)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToBinary(ParquetDictionary.java:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.WritableColumnVector.getUTF8String(WritableColumnVector.java:380)
```

UPDATE 2:

Now i found that there is schema mismatch in  one of the column one is string other is float.I have depicted the scenario below.
Here you can see col1 column is string in one row and float for other row

```
org_id, device_id, channel_id, source,    col1, col2
"100"    "device1"  "channel"   "source1"  10    0.1
"100"    "device1"  "channel"   "source2"  "10"  0.1
```

I tried casting col1 column to float.it dodn;t worked

Any suggestion.

Comment: Can you try forcing a schema on read to your dataframe keeping all columns as string and then running a df.show() because the error can be with other columns also?

Comment: @ShubhamJain Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Try force type casting all `partition_columns` to `StringType`

Answer (score 0):

Root cause of the issue is mentioned in UPDATE2. In my case we have 4 apps(part of different pipeline based on source) that write to parquet store. 2 app APP1 and APP2 don't use col1 and APP 3 used to write it as float.
Recently APP4  started getting col1 in their data and stored it as string in the parquet.parquet don't complain while writing.
While reading such parquet made

1. I tried casting it didn't worked
2. merge schema failed with mismatch in data type
3. I tried filter data based on source type. it worked partially in the sense if filter out APP4 data it worked.but if filter out APP3 data it didn't worked.

This may not be good solution, but i had to content with this for now.

**Solutions:**
1. filter out app4 source data and create data frame and convert it parquet and then filter only app4 source parquet in data frame and remove col1 and convert it into parquet.

2. Or Remove col from whole data frame and write to parquet.

df1 =df.select([c for c in df.columns if c!= 'col1'])

Comment: Since parquet contains the datatype information so we cannot even explicitly make it all string while reading. If possible keep parquet file generated from both source at two different locations and once you read them as two dataframes you can merge both dataframes by casting columns as once read you can cast easily.